# Isomorphy of abstract vs. algebraic groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$ and let 
$n$ be a power $p$. In this case, the abstract groups $SL_{n}(K)$ and $PGL_{n}(K)$ are isomorphic under the natural map $\alpha:SL_{n}(K)\to PGL_{n}(K)$.

**Question 1.** Are they also isomorphic as algebraic groups?

If the answer is "no", then I have another question.
Since $\alpha$ is an isogeny (in particular, a morphism), its inverse $\alpha^{-1}$ must not be a morphism 
of algebraic varieties.

**Question 2.** Can it be seen directly why $\alpha^{-1}$ is not a morphism?

Comment: Perhaps the article by [Steinberg](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiZoYji_77bAhUmGZoKHbsKAFgQFggwMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fpii%2FS0021869398977766%2Fpdf%3Fmd5%3Dbe946b6d3cdce2d08f826ca980bc2b03%26pid%3D1-s2.0-S0021869398977766-main.pdf%26_valck%3D1&usg=AOvVaw2dodRNNsRuRI8Xxq1NRG5b) is helpful, e.g. $4.11$ on page $377$.